# Problems with the Jquery iCal plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, icalendar

Hey just wondering if anyone has used or knows how to use the jQuery iCal plugin made by Stefano Verna? The jQuery file is being called and is creating the calendar, the style is working, but i cannot figure out how to connect it to my database so that days with events show up on the calendar and show coda popup on mouseover? i found very little help so far, only this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#ical").ical({ 
eventdates: [
<?php 
include ("Includes/dbConnect.php");


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM events";

$checkevent = mysqli_query($cxn,$query2) or die("Couldn't execute query!");
$count = 0;                                 



while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($checkevent)):

if ($count == 0) echo '{'; else echo ',{';
$count++;

$eventDate = $row2['eventDate'];
$eventName = $row2['eventName'];
$eventHost = $row2['host'];
echo '"date": "' . $eventDate . '",';
echo '"title": "' . $eventName . '",';
echo '"desc": "' . $eventHost . '"';
echo '}';

endwhile; 
?>
 ] 
 });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:
https://github.com/MrHus/jquery-monthly-ical